# Configure dynamic redirects(nginx + SPA)

Tags: angular, nginx, redirect, single-page-application

We have the website on Angular and NGINX on server. Website is dedicated to be an aggregator of information about public events(concerts, shows, movies)

As soon as it is SPA, we return the same `index.html` on any request.
But we need to add possibility to *dynamically* configure redirects on our website – return 301 code for some requests.

This case is needed to let our managers to redirect users from one event page to another(for example some event has expired, but we want old link to redirect to new event or to totally another site).

As soon we need real 301 code to be sent(because of SEO and the fact that we might want to redirect to extenal websites), the only solution to make redirects – configure them on NGINX

But they need to be *dynamic*, so NGIXNG should be restarted each time we make changes in redirects list. This is not a solution obviously.

Is there better solutions(I know there must be)?